# Problem regarding comunities display list

Tags: support, communities-list

I am part of four communities here on Stack Exchange. But in my *"Your Communities"* list it only shows one. Why is this?

Comment: Can you add a link to that list?  When I looked just now via your network profile you appeared to be part of five communities (including this one).

Comment: New sites you join are not added automatically to the list, you have to manually add them.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Well now I am part of 6. And what do you meant by adding link to the list? How can I do that?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: How?

Comment: By clicking the "edit" link besides the caption.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Thanks, Its done.